# TS: assign function to `const` with generic type

Tags: typescript, generics

In pre TS world, we used to assign simple HOC to const like this. (code uses [recompose/mapProps](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#mapprops))

```
const withAverage = mapProps(
    (props) => ({ ...props, average: avg(props.numbers) })
)
```

in TS world the code looks like this (it's not 100% accurate, but illustrate the problem)

```
const withAverage = <R extends DataRow, P extends WithData<R>>(
  component: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.ComponentType<P & WithAverage<R>> =>
  mapProps<P, P & WithAverage<R>>(
    (props) => ({ ...props, average: avg(props.numbers) })
(component);
```

the TypeScript version wraps HOC function in another HOC function, but it is not necessary, `mapProps` already provides HOC so just

```
const withAverage = mapProps...
```

is sufficient, no need to wrap it in another function like

```
const withAverage = Component => mapProps(...)(Component)
```

but AFAIK, there is no way how to assign HOC to `const` with support for generics, something like

```
const withAverage<I,O> = mapProps<I, O>(...)
```

Generics seem to be only supported for function declaration, not for HOC assignment. Or Am I wrong?

Comment: Semantically this doesn't make any sense since a `const` is a variable or a particular implementation of a class or interface. A function or class that is generic is still a blueprint nonetheless. Only by explicitly defining your generic type parameters you will get a concrete instance of a function or class that is assignable to a variable and thus a `const` as well.

Comment: Additionally you should attempt to leverage as much as possible of the type inference of TypeScript. Something along the lines of `const withFoo = <P extends any>(WrappedComponent: ComponentType<P>) => (props: P) => <Wrapper><WrappedComponent {...props} /></Wrapper>;` which can be used as `const HigherOrderComponent = withFoo(BaseComponent);`.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic consider I would use the type inference, and since `mapProps` could infer type from callback, I can write something like this `const myDecorator = mapProps(modifyProps)` and consider, that function `modifyProps` is generic and I would like to add type restrictions on `myDecorator`, so I would like to write something like `const myDecorator<T extends E> = mapProps(modifyProps<T>)` or `... = mapProps<P & { tProp: T }>(...)`, but both cases are invalid. It annoys me that you could not use generics with function composition other than wrap it in another function declaration.